# How to set files public directory programmatically?

Tags: 7, files, multi-sites

I have standalone script for adding some files to Drupal nodes. It is in main Drupal directory. It is multisite enviromnent. I know how to choose database and I am sure that I am choosing proper database, but my files lands in `sites/default/files` but I want them in `sites/domain/files`. I am getting public files path by

```
drupal_realpath('public://')
```

It returns `sites/default/files`.

All other things are correct and file data lands in proper database.

I checked site (admin/config/media/file-system) that database I am using and this path is set to `site/domain/files`...

Is there any chance to set public path programmatically? So `file_copy` will use proper path.

**EDIT**

The reason that I am asking is that my hooks: `hook_file_presave` doesn't invoke and I am thinking that is because public path problem. (All required module are enabled)

In single site env script works ok.

Probably the only solution is to create module, but it strange it isn't works. 
I wanted to stay away from creating modules for long running task because it's take longer and Batch API is slower that good old CLI. All my previous scripts worked with multisites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set that variable like so:

```
variable_set('file_public_path', 'sites/domain/files');
```

Hopefully someone else will be able to tell you why this problem is happening, I have no such issue in any of my multisite installations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Hooks still doesn't invoke, but it is different problem.